# ImportError: cannot import name 'extract_email' from 'helpers

Tags: importerror, instagram-api, helper

```
import instascrape

scraper = instascrape.InstagramScraper()

usernames = ["lonepsi", "ragdoll_brotherz", "kendricklamar"]


for username in usernames:

    media = scraper.scrape_user_medias(username, count=10)

    for photo in media:
        print(f"Média ID: {photo['id']}")
        print(f"Propriétaire du média: {photo['owner']['username']}")
        print(f"Description: {photo['caption']}")
        print(f"Nombre de likes: {photo['like_count']}")
        print(f"Date de création: {photo['taken_at_timestamp']}")
```

I'm trying to collect data on instagram with instascrape but when I run my code here is what I get as a response :

```
from helpers import extract_email
ImportError: cannot import name 'extract_email' from 'helpers' (D:\Users\Paul\Documents\inge_3\projet_insta\post-acquisition\venv\lib\site-packages\helpers\__init__.py)
```

i tried several solutions but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, and it was because I used the wrong command to install `instascrape`. I used `pip3 install instascrape`, **but the correct command is**:

```
pip3 install insta-scrape
```

This is their pypi page: https://pypi.org/project/insta-scrape/